# SQL - Northwind DB - Most profitable employees

Tags: sql, database, northwind

I'm having some troubles with my SQL queries practicing Northwind DB (SQL Server).

DB: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Database_Examples/Northwind/SQL_Server

I can determine which are the most profitable employees according to the amount of orders they have with the following query:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, count(*) as TotalOrders
FROM Orders
GROUP BY EmployeeID
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

| EmployeeID | TotalOrders |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 40 |
| 3 | 31 |
| 1 | 29 |
| 8 | 27 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 6 | 18 |
| 7 | 14 |
| 5 | 11 |
| 9 | 6 |

But now I want to determine the employees with the most profits according to the amount of orders they have and also the money generated from their sold products in another column. Did something like this but I'm pretty sure its wrong:

```
SELECT E.EmployeeID, E.FirstName, E.LastName, COUNT(O.OrderID) AS TotalOrders, SUM(P.Price * OD.Quantity) AS TotalProfit
FROM Employees E
JOIN Orders O ON E.EmployeeID = O.EmployeeID
JOIN OrderDetails OD ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
JOIN Products P ON OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
GROUP BY E.EmployeeID, E.FirstName, E.LastName
ORDER BY TotalProfit DESC;
```

The result:
You can see now that the quantity in TotalOrders has changed. For example, in the first query Anne Dodsworth (Employee ID 9) had only 6 generated orders, now she has 19, and I don't know where is the error.

| EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName | TotalOrders | TotalProfit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Margaret | Peacock | 123 | 105926 |
| 1 | Nancy | Davolio | 78 | 57765 |
| 3 | Janet | Leverling | 74 | 42823 |
| 7 | Robert | King | 34 | 39843 |
| 8 | Laura | Callahan | 68 | 39341 |
| 2 | Andrew | Fuller | 49 | 32559 |
| 5 | Steven | Buchanan | 27 | 27606 |
| 6 | Michael | Suyama | 46 | 25501 |
| 9 | Anne | Dodsworth | 19 | 15702 |

Hope someone can help me
Thank you!

To summarize: I want to obtain the most profit employees according to who generated the most revenue based on the sales they had, not their amount of orders

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Each order row is repeated multiple times because of the joins (and each order having more than one product). So, count the Unique orders instead... `COUNT(DISTINCT O.OrderID)`

Comment: Try COUNT(DISTINCT O.OrderID) instead.  Once you join to the OrderDetails table then the recordset that SQL is evaluating is going to contain multiple rows with the same OrderID (because every OrderDetails record will have an OrderID value, to relate it back to the Orders table).  By counting only the DISTINCT OrderID values, you will then get the same result as your COUNT(*) when querying just the Orders table

Comment: Why would you need the `OrderDetails` table?

Comment: Thank u guys! @Craig / @MatBailie! The issue was there, I wasn't counting unique orders with DISTINCT.

Comment: @Eric Because from OrderDetails, I obtain the information about the quantity of products (Quantity column) to later multiply it by the prices of the products (Products table, Price column). I didn't find another way to relate them.